# Printer not recognized on Ubuntu Libre Office?

Tags: 14.04, printing, libreoffice, hp

I have an HP Officejet J4660 All-inOne printer and I want to print files with Libre Office but it doesn't recognize the printer no matter what I do, am I missing something or the printer is just unsupported (Ubuntu version 14.04) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you double checked that hplip is installed and updated?

According to the HPLIP website, your printer should be close to fully supported.

http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/models/officejet/officejet_j4660_series.html

Open a terminal and type

sudo apt-get install hplip

If it says "hplip is already the latest version", then there may be another issue.